# Line 1, Column 2 error in Minecraft while using /give command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been attempting to use the /give command in Minecraft: Pocket Edition (which uses the Bedrock engine). I am on the most recent version: 1.2.10 (I think the most recent is 1.2.10, not sure, but I know I am fully updated)

I am attempting to /give myself a diamond sword with Sharpness 10. I have read that this is possible with commands. Here is the command I am using:

`/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:{id:16,lvl:10}}`

The following error is returned:

`*Line 1, Column 2
Missing '}' or object member name`

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong. And, if possible, could anyone give me the proper command that would work?

REMEMBER: I am running Minecraft: PE which uses different command syntax than Java (computer) or the consoles. I am running version 1.2.10

Comment: you're definitely not using 1.12, as that is the Java version. Bedrock is currently on 1.2.10

Comment: @Plagiatus that is correct, my bad

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using there are in fact Java commands.

The only thing you can add to a items in bedrock without external tools (as of 1.2.10) are `can_place_on` and `can_destroy`.

Comment: Is there any other way to enchant something like that? I know that I could use /enchant but that only allows for enchanting up to the normal in-game levels.

Comment: Like i hinted at in my answer, you can use external data editor tools such as mctoolchest to edit an existing item to have that desired enchantment.